# Convert json to string

Tags: javascript, json

My string is :-
   `var str = '{ name : "some name", prop : "some class=\"className\"" }';` 
How do I convert it to javascript object?

I want something like this:-

`obj.name` should return  `some name`

Comment: How are you getting that string in the first place? It's not valid JSON, but it's valid JavaScript.

Comment: What will be the valid json string for this?

Comment: Does your code really look like that? If so, there's no point in it starting out as a string. Just make it an ordinary JavaScript object literal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your code *really* looks like this:

```
var str = '{ name : "some name", prop : "some class=\"className\"" }';
```

then all you really need to do is create a JavaScript object literal instead:

```
var obj = { name : "some name", prop : 'some class="className"' };
```

If you really do want that in string form, create the object literal and then stringify it:

```
var obj = { name : "some name", prop : 'some class="className"' };
var str = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: I will change the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = JSON.parse(str);
```

will work on most browsers without including the JSON library.

Comment: This won't work with the string in the OP; it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Valid Json: `{ "name" : "some name", "prop" : "some class=\"className\"" }`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to modify the string.

```
  var str = '{"name":"some name","prop":"some class=className"}';
  var obj = JSON.parse(str);
  console.log(obj.name );
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/vgb7qwhj/

Comment: The `console.log()` won't happen because the string is not valid JSON.